# How to send F1 key to 3270 terminal emulator using Microsoft HIS

Tags: 3270

I'm using Microsoft Host Integration Server (HIS 2006) to connect to 3270 IBM Mainframe terminal to send keys and get responses programmatically. But I am unable to send the F1 key.

If I am using the HIS server 3270 client manually pressing the F1 key will show me the next page of the response. After recording the manual process in the client I found out it sends @1 as a key programmatically as shown below. But it is not working when I send the key programmatically. 
Here is the code snippet  (I’m using the classes in Microsoft.HostIntegration.SNA.Session dll)

..
SessionDisplay handler = new SessionDisplay();
....
handler.SendKey("@1");
Does anyone know how to send F1 key programmatically using Microsoft HIS 2006 or which key to send to go from page to page in 3270 terminal emulator programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the cursor position before sending the F1 key solved the problem